# Laravel getting realtionship with auth()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4, relation

I have the following relationship in `User`.

```
public function partner()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Partner','partner_id');
}
```

And I am accessing that relationship

```
auth()->user()->partner()->name
```

But it gives me exception where `name` is available in `partners` table:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$name`

And the user object from `auth()->user()->partner()` is also empty.

**What am I missing?**

Comment: What Laravel version are using?

Answer (score 1):

`auth()->user()->partner()` returns the relation binding, not the model itself.

try `auth()->user()->partner->name` instead.

Comment: Following error : `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'partners.user_id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Could you add a picture/schematic of your database table structure?

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure you setup the right relationship:

**User.php**

```
public function partner()
{
  return $this->hasOne('App\Partner');
}
```

**Partner.php**

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

To access the user's partner:

```
// Get the user's Partner instance:
$partner = auth()->user()->partner;

// Access the user's partner properties:
$partner_name = auth()->user()->partner->name;
```

Also, check that your `partners` table has the column `user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it wrong, All you have to do is that to change :

```
public function partner()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Partner','partner_id');
}
```

to

```
public function partner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Partner');
}
```

A user belongs to a partner, Cause partner is a meta table.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you so much